# Why doesnt sound decrease by 12db?

Tags: acoustics

Considering omni-directional sound source,why doesnt sound decrease by 12db per doubling of distance?

I read about sound decreasing with distance and everybody claim that sound decrease 6db per doubling of distance,that is in my opinion impossible and completly wrong becose the soundwave will spread 4x in area,it will double in both height and width,that means one fourth or 25%.

I read on site called Sengpiel audio that sound decreases 12db per doubling in near field and them 6db in far field,I also read that sound in near field doesnt decrease at all,instead it fluctuates up and down chaoticaly.

Comment: What decreases by 12dB is the sound intensity (acoustic energy). However, the sound intensity is proportional to the sound pressure squared or, in deciBells, doubled. So the sound pressure drops by a half of 12dB or 6dB.

Answer (score 1):

The Sound pressure $p$ decreases with the distance $r$ from the source as:

$p \propto \frac{1}{r}$.

The effective Sound pressure you obtain by computing the time average of the square of the pressure fluctuation $p(t)$ dependent on time $t$, i.e. for the effective Sound pressure it holds

$P = \sqrt {\frac{1}{T} \int_0^T p^2(t)dt}$

for a characteristic time $T$. For fixed distance $r$ you also get $P \propto 1/r$. To get the Sound pressure Level in dB you have to compute

$P_{dB} =20 \log_{10} P$.

The difference in Sound pressure Levels between being at the source at $r$ and being at the source at $2r$ will be

$P_{dB}(2r)-P_{dB}(r) = 20 \log_{10} \frac{K}{2r} - 20 \log_{10} \frac{K}{r} = 20 \log_{10} (\frac{K}{2r}/ \frac{K}{r}) = - 20 \log_{10} 2$

that is exactly 6 dB.

Comment: Please can you make answer without equations? I have equation skills of potato,use words only.

Comment: The other definition is in terms of power and amounts to the same thing. More equations here http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Sound/db.html

Answer (score 1):

You say there is a envelope spread of 4x when distance doubles. That is correct. So the acoustic **energy** per unit area falls by 4x. This is required for conservation of energy.

The convention with decibel language for **energy** is **10log(energy)** so 4x is 6 dB.

Sound pressure, mentioned in other responses, is proportional to the *square root of the energy* (aka amplitude), hence it falls down by a factor of 2.

Nevertheless, there is no ambiguity in decibel language. For amplitude related factors, the convention is **20log(amplitude)**, which again is 6 dB.

Comment: This is best response so far,I am ready to accept it but I am still super confused.It seems like for some things 6db is double,while for other things 3db is double.There is three "things" mentioned in your answer,Energy,Pressure and Amplitude.I understand that doubling speed quadruples kinetic energy,correct me if I wrong but in this case term Energy and Power are same thing.I also think Amplitude and Pressure are same thing,we are talking about amplitude of pressure.You say sound pressure is square root of amplitude,I have no idea why and I also believe amplitude = pressure,not energy.

Comment: Correct me if I wrong,but doubling Pressure also doubles Particle Velocity and double speed = quadruple kinetic energy.

Comment: For this discussion, Amplitude and Pressure go together. Energy and Power go together. I wrote pressure is proportional to square root of energy, not to square root of amplitude. As for dB, i wrote the prescription when handling amplitude vs energy. -3dB is 0.5 energy and about o.7 amplitude.

Comment: "proportional to the square root of the energy (aka amplitude)"

Comment: Sorry. "Square root of energy" aka amplitude.

Comment: Check this: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/powstr.html for relating kinetic and potential particle energies to power transferred by wave.